# Reset postgres password v9.1

Tags: postgresql, authentication, pg-hba.conf

I'm trying to reset my lost password for Postgres v9.1 (windows 7) like written at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#I_lost_the_database_password._What_can_I_do_to_recover_it.3F  :

```
1. edit pg_hba.conf to allow trust authorization temporarily
```

In pg_hba.conf I've put :

> local all all trust
>
> host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust

```
2. Reload the config file (pg_ctl reload)
```

Done. I have also restarted the Postgres service (via services.msc)

```
3. Connect and issue ALTER ROLE / PASSWORD to set the new password
```

Then I execute 'psql.exe' but **it asks me for a password !**

Why ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You put the new `pg_hba.conf` entries at the end, so the other ones take priority. Put them at the start.

Comment: The entries are already at the beginning of the file

Comment: Are you sure you edited the right `pg_hba.conf` file?  or connecting to the right PostgreSQL instance?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to run `psql -h 127.0.0.1 (...)`

When you use the `-h` that will tell `psql` to use a TCP/IP connection
('h' is from host), and the parameter after `-h` is the name of the host.

In that case `127.0.0.1` is a default address, meaning localhost.

If you don't use the `-h` (with host next to this parameters) it will
use a "local way" of connection called unix domain sockets.

Comment: The OP is on Windows, so there is no socket, unfortunately.

Comment: Using -h and -u helps me to resolve this issue, thanks.

Comment: I'm confused though because his question shows he had `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust` that should be triggering with `-h` and as @dezso said, mswin doesn't have sockets.